# For SAT test.....

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

What is the maximum number of rectangular blocks measuring $3$ inches by $2$ by $1$ inch that can be packed into a cube-shaped box whose interior measure 6 inches on an edge?
 
A) $24$
B) $28$
C) $30$
D) $36$
E) $40$

Comment: Can you arrange some of those blocks to make a $6\times 6\times 1$ inch layer? Do that $6$ times, stack up the layers, and you’ve completely filled the box, so you obviously can’t fit any more blocks than that.